# LSTM input and output in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I am doing a binary classification where my **X_train** size is **(2900,15,5)** and **Y_train** size is **(2900,1)**. After training the model, I should get the X_train_prediction **(2900,1)** but I am getting **(2900,15,1)**. Below is my keras model.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),
                      return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='BinaryCrossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2
                    , callbacks=[callback])
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: set return_sequences=False in the last LSTM cell

Comment: Worked, can you please explain the reason as well?

Comment: this is how LSTM works. you can find more https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM or find on the internet something that explains LSTM

Comment: Not much else can be said. Setting _return_sequences_ to True will return sequences.